# Problem retrieving SWF from PHP script

Tags: html, flash

So why won't this URL for the Flash source file won't work for embedding in the HTML?

src='http://65.19.134.36/uploader/?uuid=suhFolmJnCL3T_7oJ1rkxyeP4oSQtbzf.swf'

(or as used in the object tag for value="...")

There must be *something* that Flash doesn't like about it, but I cannot figure it out. I've even made a quick fix to the PHP as the original code should've been this, which didn't work either:

src='http://65.19.134.36/uploader/?uuid=suhFolmJnCL3T_7oJ1rkxyeP4oSQtbzf&type=000'

That page serves a SWF file with the correct filename and mimetype, so it seems to be something else. Maybe related to 'http://65.19.134.36/uploader/' being seen as the swf file and the query string being appended to that? I've tried replacing the ampersand with &3F; and & but it makes no difference.

I'm sure this will be a 'bang my head on the desk when I know the answer' question. Can anyone put me out of my misery??

Cheers,

Mark...

Comment: I would guess that you are right about the query string issue. Would using mod_rewrite (or similar) on the server, to get rid of the query string construct, be a viable workaround?

Comment: Aha! After looking at this very quickly, I see that something like this could achieve the aim:

RewriteRule ^([0-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /?uuid=$1&type=$2

So this would map:
'65.19.134.36/uploader/suhFolmJnCL3T_7oJ1rkxyeP4oSQtbzf/000' to the URL in the original question.

Possibly. I can imagine that there is much more to it than I can see after a quick 10 minute investigation.

Definitely worth looking into more though. Thanks for the idea! And how do you get line feeds in coments?? ;)

Comment: Got the rewrite working, but still no luck. SWF will only play if it's a static file on the server. It must be something else...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460677/serving-raw-swf-files-displays-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie has the answer - the 'attachment' was causing the problem when the transcoder was returning the swf.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `<object>` tag the attribute should be `data` and not `src`. you can easy trace whether or not the swf has been loaded inside the net tab in your firebug.